# Validating a collection or enumerable of unknown type

Tags: c#, casting, ienumerable

I'm looking to add an Attribute validation to my model, to ensure that a collection property has items. Perhaps there is a better way to validate the collection in my model. If so, I'd be happy to use that.

Otherwise, I can cast the object to IEnumerable, but as an interface I cannot use .Any(). I was trying to use reflection to get a more concrete type at runtime, but must have my dummy hat on today.

```
public class MyModel
{
    ... // other properties
    [CollectionHasAtLeastOne]
    public virtual ICollection<MyItemObject> Items { get; set; }
}
```

In my `CollectionHasAtLeastOneAttribute : ValidationAttribute` class:

```
protected override ValidationResult IsValid(object? value, ValidationContext validationContext)
{
    var testObject = (IEnumerable)value; // Can I read the type and cast to that?
    if (testObject == null)
    {
        return new ValidationResult("Collection object cannot be null.");
    }

    if (!testObject.Any()) // Can't use .Any() here
    {
        return new ValidationResult("Collection must have records.");
    }

    return ValidationResult.Success;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

You can avoid casts (well, `is` is a cast, but not the old-school C# cast) and LINQ by using the enumerator itself.

```
protected override ValidationResult IsValid(object? value, ValidationContext validationContext)
{
    if (value is not IEnumerable testObject)
    {
        return new ValidationResult("Collection object cannot be null.");
    }

    if (!testObject.GetEnumerator().MoveNext())
    {
        return new ValidationResult("Collection must have records.");
    }

    return ValidationResult.Success;
}
```

The first puts a non-null `IEnumerable` in `testObject` if it can, but if it can't then it returns.

The second gets the enumerator from `testObject` and tries to move to the first item. If it can't it returns.

To change this so all versions of C# since enumerators were introduced, change the first `if` to

```
var testIbject = value as IEnumerable;
if (testObject == mull)
```

Answer (score 0):

you can pass the type to the validation attribute
`CollectionHasAtLeastOneAttribute<T>`

```
public class CollectionHasAtLeastOneAttribute<T> : ValidationAttribute
{
    protected override ValidationResult IsValid(object? value, ValidationContext validationContext)
    {
        if (value == null) throw new ArgumentNullException("value");


        var testObject = value as IEnumerable<T>; // Can I read the type and cast to that?
        if (testObject == null)
        {
            return new ValidationResult("Collection object cannot be null.");
        }

        if (testObject.Any())
        {
            return new ValidationResult("Collection must have records.");
        }

        return ValidationResult.Success;
    }
}




public class MyModel
{

    [CollectionHasAtLeastOne<MyItemObject>]
    public virtual ICollection<MyItemObject> Items { get; set; }
}
```

**Support older C# versions**

```
public class CollectionHasAtLeastOneAttribute<T> : ValidationAttribute
{
    public Type Type { get; set; }
    protected override ValidationResult IsValid(object? value,     ValidationContext validationContext)
    {
        if (value == null) throw new ArgumentNullException("value");


        var testObject = value as IEnumerable<Type>; // Can I read the type and cast to that?
        if (testObject == null)
        {
            return new ValidationResult("Collection object cannot be null.");
        }

        if (testObject.Any())
        {
            return new ValidationResult("Collection must have records.");
        }

        return ValidationResult.Success;
    }
}
```

**Usage**

```
[CollectionHasAtLeastOneWithTypeAttribute(Type = typeof(MyItemObject))]
```

Comment: Same remark, `ICollection<T>` does not implement `ICollection`

Comment: Oh, that looks good, but we're still using c# 8.0. :(

Comment: @MKenyonII I got it and tried a small workaround.